# How does a resistor really alter the voltage across it?

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

**[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/494051/212841)** sums up the reason why a resistor does not alter the current flowing through it in a  circuit.

Let's say that we have a $10$ $V$ battery connected with two resistors of resistance $3$ and $2$ $ohm$ respectively in series.

Then we can use ohm's law to find out that a current of $2 A$ flows through the circuit and that we have a potential drop of $4$ $V$ and and 6 $V$ across the $2$ $\Omega$ and $3$ $\Omega$ resistors respectively.

The above process can be and is conveniently described by Ohms law.

**However I am curious that how on a microscopic level do these resistors individually manage to lower the Voltage across them , is it due to some internal electric field created inside the resistors or something else ?**

Comment: Related if not duplicate [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14941/)

Comment: try http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmmic.html

Comment: I wrote [a answer to an earlier question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/215807/520) where I examined the things that happen (*very* quickly in most cases) when a circuit is switched on or otherwise changed in configuration. The nice steady-state flows that we study in intro circuits *are established* by the interactions of very basic rules, but if you are unwilling to simply accept the results you have to study those interactions.

Comment: Also note that any potential drop by definition comes from electric fields.

Comment: I disapprove of the wording "individually manage". Resistors are not individuals. Resistors do not manage. Resistors resist. Managers manage.

Comment: How does a balance keep two equal weights at heights? How does the floor know to push back up on you with exactly the same force you're pushing down on it with?